# In magento 2 Clear Local Storage key value On Update Cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

in magento 2 i want to clear local storage key (local_key) value on any cart changes like product add,update,delete in cart

Answer (score 0):

To clear the local storage key value on any cart changes in Magento 2, you can create a custom module and use a JavaScript event observer to listen to the cart changes and clear the local storage key value. Here are the steps to achieve this:

Create a custom module:
Create a custom module in your Magento 2 instance by following the Magento 2 module development guide.

Add a JavaScript event observer:
In your custom module, create a requirejs-config.js file in the following path: app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Add the following code in the requirejs-config.js file:

```
define('clearLocalStorage', ['jquery'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('cartAjaxData', function() {
        localStorage.removeItem('local_key');
    });
});
```

This code creates a JavaScript event observer that listens to the cartAjaxData event, which is triggered on any cart changes. When the event is triggered, it removes the value of the local_key key from the local storage.

Enqueue the JavaScript file:
In your custom module, create a default.xml file in the following path: app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Add the following code in the default.xml file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="{Vendor}_{Module}::js/clearLocalStorage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

This code enqueues the JavaScript file that contains the event observer.

Test the implementation:
After implementing the above changes, you can test the implementation by adding, updating, or deleting a product from the cart. When you do this, the value of the local_key key in the local storage should be cleared.